# How to make my playing field as a grid in Ruby (Gosu)?

Tags: ruby, dictionary, grid, libgosu

So I'm attempting to make a simple Snake game. However, there's one major problem with that - I don't know how to make my playing field as a grid.

So far I've split my snake into segemnts, which are drawn every time it eats an apple. My turn method looks like that (it's analogical for every direction pretty much):

```
if @direction == :right
  x = @head.x + @speed
  y = @head.y
  new_segment = Segment.new(@window, self, [x, y])
end
```

with new_segment being immediately pushed into the array `segments`.

The problem with that is that the snake is too independant. I'd like to make it move in predetermined rows and columns a.k.a make myself a grid. Could somoene help me with that? Thank you!

Comment: This question might be more appropriate on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @CodyPoll I will consider this, thank you!